# Move discussion to chat not possible because of reputation?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to help Cyberike to define the problem given in [How do I calculate DC motor speed for a given load?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24028/how-do-i-calculate-dc-motor-speed-for-a-given-load#comment56280_24028) so that there is a definite answer. As the discussion might take another few posts I wanted to move it to chat but the site says that this is not possible due to Cyberike's low reputation.

Is there any other way? Should I just stick to the comments or what would you suggest?

Comment: Apparently Cyberike has managed to get 20 rep points.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the system doesn't allow those with less than 20 reputation to participate in chat. If it's just a matter of one upvote to get someone to that 20-rep mark, then you can just upvote the question (as long as it doesn't suck) and take it to a chat room. Otherwise, just stick to the comments.

I see Cyberike now has 21 rep so you should be good to go with a chat room.